# Convert image color space and output separate channels in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to reduce the runtime of a routine that converts an RGB image to a YCbCr image. My code looks like this:

```
cv::Mat input(BGR->m_height, BGR->m_width, CV_8UC3, BGR->m_imageData);
cv::Mat output(BGR->m_height, BGR->m_width, CV_8UC3);

cv::cvtColor(input, output, CV_BGR2YCrCb);

cv::Mat outputArr[3];
outputArr[0] = cv::Mat(BGR->m_height, BGR->m_width, CV_8UC1, Y->m_imageData);
outputArr[1] = cv::Mat(BGR->m_height, BGR->m_width, CV_8UC1, Cr->m_imageData);
outputArr[2] = cv::Mat(BGR->m_height, BGR->m_width, CV_8UC1, Cb->m_imageData);  

split(output,outputArr);
```

But, this code is slow because there is a redundant split operation which copies the interleaved RGB image into the separate channel images. Is there a way to make the cvtColor function create an output that is already split into channel images? I tried to use constructors of the _OutputArray  class that accepts a vector or array of matrices as an input, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that copying the image data is the limiting step?
How are you producing the Y ? Cr / Cb cv::mats?
Can you just rewrite this function to write the results into the three separate images?

Comment: It does consume runtime. I've discovered that by doing runtime profiling with VTune. The Y,Cr and Cb data buffers are preallocated so creating the cv::Mats takes negligible time. I guess I can rewrite the function, but I'd rather not waste my time on that and use a pre-existing solution.

Comment: Could you pre-allocate them as cv::mats and then pass those data pointers to the functions that produce the y/cr/cb data?

Comment: I don't know how to get cvtColor to produce separate Y,Cb,Cr channels.

Comment: @VictorMay doesn't cvtcolor() produce interleaved YUYV output? If it does then you are going to have to go through the result copying bytes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no calling option for cv::cvtColor, that gives it result as three seperate cv::Mats (one per channel).

> dst – output image of the same size and depth as src.

source: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

You have to copy the pixels from the result (as you are already doing) or write such a conversion function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use split.  This splits the image into 3 different channels or arrays.

Now converting them back to `UIImage` is where I am having trouble. I get three grayscale images, one in each array.  I am convinced they are the proper channels in cvMat format but when I convert them to `UIImage` they are grayscale but different grayscale values in each image.  If you can use `imread` and `imshow` then it should display the images for you after the split.  My problem is trying to use the ios.h methods and I believe it reassembles the arrays, instead of transferring the single array.  Here is my code using a segmented control to choose which layer, or array, you want to display.  Like I said, I get 3 grayscale images but with completely different values.  I need to keep the one layer and abandon the rest.  Still working on that part of it.

```
UIImageToMat(_img, cvImage);
cv::cvtColor(cvImage, RYB, CV_RGB2BGRA);
split(RYB, layers);
if (_segmentedRGBControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
   // cv::cvtColor(layers[0], RYB, CV_8UC1);
    RYB = layers[0];
    _imageProcessView.image = MatToUIImage(RYB);
}
if (_segmentedRGBControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    RYB = (layers[1]);
    _imageProcessView.image = MatToUIImage(RYB);
}
if (_segmentedRGBControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    RYB = (layers[2]);
    _imageProcessView.image = MatToUIImage(RYB);
}
}
```